# How to see files uploaded to google drive via PHP?

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I have been trying to upload files to my google drive account via **service-account** using php. I guess the file is successfully uploaded as I can **print the file id, file created time and all other information.**

Here is my issue: When I login into my google drive account, I cannot see any uploaded file. Where is the file hiding or what should I do?

Here is the code:

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php'; //api
$serviceAccount     = "xxx@xxxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com";
$key_file       = "mykey-goes-here.p12";
$auth = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
                    $serviceAccount,
                    array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'),
                    file_get_contents($key_file)
                    );
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAssertionCredentials( $auth );

$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

 $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
  $file->setTitle("my file name");
 $file->setDescription('testing desc');
 $file->setMimeType('text/plain');
                // Provide file name here and path in below 

  $result = $service->files->insert($file, array(
  'data' => file_get_contents("test.txt"),
//'mimeType' => 'text/plain',
  'mimeType' => 'application/octet-stream',
  'uploadType' => 'media',
 //'uploadType' => 'multipart'
));

 // Uncomment the following line to print the File ID
   printf("File ID: %s\n", $result->id);


echo "<br><br>";
echo '<pre>'; print_r($result); echo'</pre>';
```

Comment: If you upload a file manually, can you access it with the PHP code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**solution:**

I discovered that Files uploaded by service account is not available via UI.

To solve the issue, one need to delegate/authorize the application to use the said service account.
[link](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/authentication/delegation)